# LED Lights Dimmer Electronics

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, electrical, consumer-electronics

I have a Wemo Smart WiFi Smart Dimmer with me that can control CFL, Incandescent and LED lights. (https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F7C059/).

I am curious to know how one device can handle all type of bulbs.

As I understand that,
In order to dim the light, usually, Triac/Solid State switches are used. They are generally called phase-cut dimmers. They can be either leading edge, trailing edge or universal dimmers. These usually go well with CFL and Incandescent lights. These dimmers circuits accept 230V 50Hz input for operation.

Now, if I want to control a LED light, I probably will need a LED driver. These LED drivers work on PWM on either constant voltage or constant current.

So Wemo Smart dimmer works for all kinds of the bulb, they will have to have a LED driver inbuilt and an AC/DC converter to convert the 230V AC to DC for LED lights.

Now, I am not sure If I am right. 
What do you think?

P.S - A shout out to the explanation Rod Elliott (http://sound.whsites.net/lamps/dimmers.html). It's a very well written piece of information on LED dimmers.

Edit:

I think I had a bit of misunderstanding. I think that the Wemo Smart dimmer can only control LED bulbs that are rated 230V. Bulbs like these( https://www.philips.co.id/c-p/8718696485583/led-bulb). And then you will need to a LED driver to control LED bulbs like MR16 LED bulbs (http://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/led-lamps-and-tubes/led-spots/mr16-gu10-par16). They are rated 12V...24V DC-DC with either constant current or constant voltage.

But again I want to make sure that my direction of thinking is right. I am no expert on LED lightning.

Comment: Well, it does have "smart" in its name :-) .   Presumably this gadget can "probe" the reactance & impedance of the bulb it's driving and make educated guesses as to how best to operate the system.

Comment: Yes. It does it very smartly :-) I wanted to understand how it does smartly. For example, I know in the case of the Universal Light dimmer (they can be either trailing edge or leading edge), they identify what type of peaks they get during 'phase cut' and shift their operation accordingly (again I am guessing this).